# Specflow plugin failure for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ui-automation, specflow

I have both VS 2015 Update 3 and VS 2017 15.7 installed on my machine. After installing new VS2017 I downloaded the specflow for visual studio 2017 to install in VS 2017 Enterprise (15.7)

I am able to build the code after I do getlatest but not when I edit. When I try to Add New Item a new feature file I am not able to do this using VS 2017 I can't see the SpecFlow feature template, or, indeed, any SpecFlow template. I get following error when I am trying to build after I edit/Add a line in the feature file - 
Below is the error in .cs file for respective feature file :-

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Enumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.NamedInstanceDictionaryRegistration.Resolve(ObjectContainer container, RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.ResolveObject(RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath, String name)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.UnitTestConverter.FeatureGeneratorRegistry..ctor(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
t System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.TestGeneratorFactory.CreateGenerator(ProjectSettings projectSettings)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.VisualStudio.CodeBehindGenerator.Actions.GenerateTestFileAction.GenerateTestFile(GenerateTestFileParameters opts)
```

[specflow](/questions/tagged/specflow)[visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017)

Others in my team are able to build the latest code as well as they are able to edit feature file and build it successfully. How do I fix this issue on my local? I don't see any other updated version of SpecFlow  where this issue got fixed. Please advise.

Comment: Regenerating feature files did not help.

Comment: Please open an issue on https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow for this.

Comment: @AndreasWillich - github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1206